# Sorting is not get applied for Extraction Query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

I have created compound index on two fields in asc order.

```
db.users.createIndex( { "currentDate": 1, "currentTimeStamp": 1 } )
```

I have around 5M of records for each day. while executing below query. I haven't received data into asc sorted manner although index I have created in asc order. Due to which I am facing duplicate transactions in the result set while doing pagination with help of skip and limit. But if I applied sort() explicitly then haven't faced duplicates transactions, but performance get impacted.

```
db.users.find(
   { currentDate: '20230613', currentTimeStamp: '121212' }
)
```

I have below queries :
If Index is in asc order then by default should I get the result in sorted manner?

Is there any way to get the records in sorting manner, without using sort()? Because getting performance issue after applying sort() explicitly.

I really appreciated if someone can help in this.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an index in MongoDB, it's important to note that it doesn't automatically sort your records for all queries. To sort your results, you need to specify the fields that should be sorted. If you have already created an index, MongoDB will utilize it for sorting.

For more detailed information, you can refer to the following documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-with-a-single-field-index.

In your specific case, since you have created the index { "currentDate": 1, "currentTimeStamp": 1 }, you should use the following sort function:

```
.sort({ "currentDate": 1, "currentTimeStamp": 1 })
```